# Hibernate Annotations - Case Insensitive UniqueConstraint

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I have an entity annotated with the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"})})
public class Component extends Model {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to make the UniqueConstraint case insensitive? We are using PostgreSQL.

Comment: It's possible in PostgreSQL, but I don't know how you'd tell Hibernate about it.  In SQL you'd just create a unique index on the lower- or upper-case value of the column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With PostgreSQL, you would indeed do something like this to implement your requirement:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX My_Index on Component (lower(name));
```

But there is to my knowledge no way to achieve this using annotations.

The only option I can think of if you want to rely on Hibernate's `hbm2ddl` tool to generate the schema and still have that index created would be to **leverage the `import.sql` feature**. From the [Rotterdam JBug and Hibernate's import.sql](http://relation.to/9081.lace) blog post:

> #### import.sql: easily import data in your unit tests
>
> Hibernate has a neat little feature
>   that is heavily under-documented and
>   unknown. You can execute an SQL script
>   during the `SessionFactory` creation
>   right after the database schema
>   generation to import data in a fresh
>   database. You just need to add a file
>   named `import.sql` in your classpath
>   root and set either `create` or
>   `create-drop` as your
>   `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property.
>
> I use it for Hibernate Search in
>   Action now that I have started the
>   query chapter. It initializes my
>   database with a fresh set of data for
>   my unit tests. JBoss Seam also uses it
>   a lot in the various examples.
>   `import.sql` is a very simple feature
>   but is quite useful at time. Remember
>   that the SQL might be dependent on
>   your database (ah portability!).
>
> ```
> #import.sql file
> delete from PRODUCTS
> insert into PRODUCTS (PROD_ID, ASIN, TITLE, PRICE, IMAGE_URL, DESCRIPTION) values ('1', '630522577X', 'My Fair Lady', 19.98, '630522577X.jpg', 'My Fair blah blah...');
> insert into PRODUCTS (PROD_ID, ASIN, TITLE, PRICE, IMAGE_URL, DESCRIPTION) values ('2', 'B00003CXCD', 'Roman Holiday ', 12.98, 'B00003CXCD.jpg', 'We could argue that blah blah');
> ```
>
> For more information about this
>   feature, check [Eyal's blog](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_s_hbm2ddl_tool) ([Updated Location for dead link](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2007/05/hibernates-hbm2ddl-tool.html)), he
>   wrote a nice little entry about it.
>   Remember if you want to add additional
>   database objects (indexes, tables and
>   so on), you can also use the
>   [auxiliary database objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-database-object)
>   feature.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest attacking this problem from a different angle:

1. add a new column, internal one, call it lcname (stands for lower-cased name)

   ```java
   @NotEmpty
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String lcname;
   ```
2. change the constraint you set as annotation to use the new field instead :

   ```java
   @Entity
   @Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"lcname"})})
   public class Component extends Model {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. modify the name setter to also set lcname with a lower case of the original name provided by the client

   ```java
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
       this.lcname = name.toLowerCase();
   }
   ```

That's it. Every time the entity will be persisted, also a lower cased name will be saved. That way if you save "A" you'll have a record with lcname = "a" saved, and next time you try to save an entity with name "a" the operation will fail due to the constraint on lcname
The change is completely transparent to anyone who fetches an entity from the database since lcname is private and there is no getter for it, while the original getName will return the original name as provided initially by the client who created it.