# Thread safe input validation

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate

I'm building an Spring Boot application which allows registering, submitting of various data and etc which requires validation. For example I have this entity setup with basic constraints:

```
@Entity
public class Account extends BaseEntity {

    public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 64;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = MAX_LENGTH)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = MAX_LENGTH)
    private String email;

    ...
}
```

Each time before creating a new account, validation is performed on the service layer:

```
public Account register(String username, String email, String rawPassword) {

    if (!accountValidator.validate(username, email, rawPassword)) {
        return null;
    }

    Account account = new Account(username, email, passwordEncoder.encode(rawPassword));
    try {
        return accountRepository.save(account);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The validator snippet:

```
public boolean validate(String username, String email, String password) {

    if (!validateUsernameStructure(username)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!validateEmailStructure(email)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!validatePasswordStructure(password)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Performs a query on all users to see if no such email or username
    // already exists. Before checking the email and username are set to
    // lowercase characters on the service layer.
    if (accountService.doesEmailOrUsernameExist(email, username)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now in this case if I get a lot of multiple requests and one of them manages to get past the validation, I will encounter an exception if the username or email is forced to be lowercase in the first place. But for example I want to allow users to register with upper case/lower case username, email characters and etc. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031709/hibernate-annotations-case-insensitive-uniqueconstraint) question I could add a additional field to my entity or add a more complex constraint on the database level, however I want to do this without overflow data and in java code.

So for example I get these two requests to create a new account milliseconds apart:

```
Request 1:
username=foo
email=foo@foo.com

Request 2:
username=foO
email=foO@foO.com
```

During this phase I check for duplicates (email and username is set to lower case, however when saving I keep the case intact):

```
if (accountService.doesEmailOrUsernameExist(email, username)) {
    return false;
}
```

However since the requests are so close to each other, the first request might not have created a new account yet so the check for the second account passes and thus I get two database entries.

So the actual question would be, how to perform thread safe validation for these kinds of actions in my service layer without huge performance impact?

**Solution I've chosen for this example**

When setting the username and email, also apply those values to their lowercase counterparts and apply unique constraints on them as well. This way I get to keep the user set case for those two properties:

```
@Entity
public class Account extends BaseEntity {

    public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 64;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = MAX_LENGTH)
    private final String username;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = MAX_LENGTH)
    private String email;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = MAX_LENGTH)
    private final String normalizedUsername;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = MAX_LENGTH)
    private String normalizedEmail;

    public Account(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;

        this.normalizedUsername = username.toLowerCase();
        this.normalizedEmail = email.toLowerCase();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, all your code is already thread safe, assuming that the several `validate*` methods and `doesEmailOrusernameExist(...)` are thread-safe too.

Comment: Hi I don't see any logic in the validator which is not thread safe. What is the issue you are encountering.

Comment: The `validate()` and `register` methods are inside Spring beans so they have only one instance, if I receive multiple request some of them go right through my validation and create multiple entries on the database. I possibly used the wrong wording by mentioning thread safety... I will add more detail to the question about the issue.

Comment: you should not prevalidate database constaints in service layer

Comment: In this example it could be handled on the database layer, but in some cases I have constraints that span over multiple properties and require some processing which includes checking creation dates and so on.

Comment: `However since the requests are so close to each other, the first request might not have created a new account yet so the check for the second account passes and thus I get two database entries.` No, you won't, because you've set up your database nicely and applied a unique constraint on the email address column. At least I very much hope you have.

Comment: @Edd Every data integrity constraint **must** be handled by the database layer. Even if you can't define the constraint declaratively, you can use transactions to do it programmatically.

Comment: @biziclop I've removed the unique constraint annotations in this example to reflect the issue I'm facing on other entities. What do you heave in mind by transactions?

Comment: @Edd For example if you need to implement a unique email address without a declarative constraint, what you can do is `start transaction->lock the table->check whether the email exists in table->insert new record->unlock table->end transaction`. But if you want to preserve your sanity, this should be done as close to the database as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple solution without the help of database because transactions are isolated from each other.

The alternative would be to temporarily store usernames/emails in memory and do complex synchronizations to perform the checks. Things would be even more complicated in clustered environments. This is very ugly and hard to maintain (and may impact performance significantly if the lock for single synchronization point is held for too long).

The standard and straightforward solution is to use database constraints.

Comment: So I'm guessing the best choice for this example - if I wanted for users to allow to create accounts with upper case/lower case usernames and emails would be to store two additional fields for these properties and always force them to be the same case and perform unique validation on them instead.

Comment: Yes, or to use some kind of unique functional index if your database supports it.